# droid: How is a trial+unlock app downloadable to other devices?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, trial, unlock

If I implement in app purchasing to unlock my app, how does that work with the purchasers downloading to second devices? If they install the trial on a second phone/tablet, will clicking the 'unlock' button in my app find the already bought unlock and unlock the app?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement **inapp billing** with **managed and subscription type products** than **purchasers id is maintained by google**

and when they **install same application** in other device and try to purchase the product with the same previous id used before, then they will see dialog that **you already own this item or Item is already purchased.**

If you use **unmanaged product type** then purchasers id will **not be maintained** and for each device install or once user uninstalls the app and again install that in same device he have to again buy the same product.

Comment: And owning the item already, they can download the unlock, right? It doesn't do something stupid like prevent them from downloading again? Just making sure here before I decide what method to implement!

Comment: You can call restoreTransactions method to restore again to the state of purchaser. I think it will not automatically allow to download unlock items.